# Singularity in Laplace Method for Orbit Determination

Tags: orbit

I have a question about Laplace angle-only method for orbit determination where the line of sight vectors are being interpolated. I read somewhere that the method fails (due to a matrix being singular) when the observation site is in the motion plane of the observed body, but failed to see proof for that. 
Could anyone explain to me why is that?

Comment: Specific questions need to be addressed by the author. You must put references on what you are talking about.